# How to send a raw input image to an MLflow served endpoint for a CNN model?

Tags: conv-neural-network, mlflow, mlops

I have started learning MLflow recently and I am trying out ML life cycle on a simple cat-dog classifier. [Here](https://github.com/abhishekPurandare-obs/mlflow_test) is the code.

I have correctly set up the model for serving using `mlflow serve`. However, there is one problem. I have configured the model signature to take a specific shape of input and the API endpoint will take an array when sending a request.

In the [send_request.py](https://github.com/abhishekPurandare-obs/mlflow_test/blob/master/send_request.py) file I am performing preprocessing for CNN input and then sending the Numpy array as a list. What I would like to do is, set up my own custom predict function for the model. So that the endpoint will only take a raw image as an input instead of an array.

I followed [this](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/tree/master/examples/flower_classifier) tutorial. But couldn't make it work for my case.

I understand that while logging/saving the model, I'll need to provide custom objects. But I am not sure how to obtain the object of the model that performs the prediction inside these custom models. There aren't many resources to refer to for this particular case.